# Spell Attack for Cantrips not of your tradition

Tags: attack, spellcasting, sorcerer, pathfinder-2e

This occured to me when reviewing the Kobold Sorcerer Grimmnir from the "[Little Trouble in Big Absalom](https://paizo.com/products/btq024ys?Pathfinder-Adventure-Little-Trouble-in-Big-Absalom)" Module.

As a Sorcerer of the demonic bloodline, Grimmnir is a spontaneous **divine** spellcaster. As indicated on p.191 Core Rulebook (2nd printing) he has these proficiencies regarding his spellcasting:

> Trained in spell attack rolls of
> your spellcasting tradition, as
> indicated by your bloodline.
> Trained in spell DCs of your
> spellcasting tradition, as
> indicated by your bloodline

That gives Grimmnir a trained (+3) bonus to his Spell Attack Roll, as well as his key ability modifier CHA (+4), resulting in a +7. This is also indicated on his pregen character sheet.

> Ranged [two-actions] acid splash +7 (cantrip), Damage 1d6 acid plus
> 1 splash

But when I looked up the [Acid Splash](https://pf2.d20pfsrd.com/spell/acid-splash/) Entry (p. 316 Core Rulebook (2nd printing)), it says Acid Splash is a cantrip of the arcane and primal tradition.

So:

1. does he actually get only a +4 (key ability modifier 4 + untrained tradition 0) ?
2. is he automatically trained in cantrips he earned from your bloodline
3. are cantrips he earned from his bloodline automatically considered of the tradition he gained from his bloodline?
4. does his spell attack work for for every spell he has, regardless of tradition?

1: would be... bad design for this bloodline? 2: you usually don't use proficiency with a single spell. 3+4: would have the same outcome here, but could work differently if there are classes that actually gain proficiency in more than one tradition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### All spells cast by the same *Class* are from the same *Tradition*.

From the rules about *[Magical Traditions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=260)*:

> Your class determines which tradition of magic your spells use. In some cases, such as when a cleric gains spells from their deity or when a sorcerer gets spells from their bloodline, you might be able to cast spells from a different spell list. In these cases, the spell uses your magic tradition, not the list the spell normally comes from. When you cast a spell, add your tradition’s trait to the spell.

From the list of options you gave, the correct one would be the 3rd.

In your example, a *Demonic Sorcerer* would add the *Divine* trait to *Acid Splash*, even if it isn't usually a divine spell, therefore using the trained proficiency for spell attacks and DCs.

I imagine that there could be an exception to this rule if a class or archetype existed that allowed you to cast spells from more than one tradition with the same spell slots, but I'm not aware that any such class exists yet.